# What does alert(colors[i]); mean

Tags: javascript

In this code, what does the (colors[i]); mean

```
var colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green"];

for(var i= 0; i < colors.length; i++){
    alert(colors[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should have read the Programming basics tutorials.

Comment: i-th element in the array: `colors[0]` is red, `colors[1]` is orange etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`colors[i]` is saying that you want to get the `i` numbered element from the `colors` array.

In an array, each item is numbered in order starting from 0 so in this case

0: red
1: orange
2: yellow
3: green

As `i` is incremented during the loop, it will get each element in the array

Answer (score 2):

The `alert()` function opens a small dialog window in your browser.

`colors[i]` will return the color from index `i` of the array `colors`.

The entire `for`-loop will thus open four dialog boxes (one after another) that show the colors contained in the array (red, orange, yellow, green).

Answer (score 0):

Colors is an array containing elements which are "red", "orange", "yellow", "green".

To access to an element of an array, you have to access through its index:

case 1 of colors = "red",
case 2 of colors = "orange", ...

the loop FOR is going to increase the variable "i" from 0 to the size of colors array.

So the variable i will increase from 0 to 4 in the loop.

colors[i] will give you the value of colors at the index "i".

it will print you in order : red, orange, yellow, green.